# Nginx PHP Yii framework How to replace Relative url to Absolute url

Tags: php, nginx, yii

I need to replace all relative urls to absolute urls in all pages of site.

I have tried to do it manually, go on each page and replace url but I think it not good way.

I need to know is there any ways to replace all url without changing in code. may be change in Nginx config file, or set global url in Yii ?

Current code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets2/css/custom.css?v=0.0.8">
```

It should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://softwaresuggest.com/assets2/css/custom.css?v=0.0.8">
```

Comment: yii\helpers\Url::canonical() ?

Comment: didn't get idea?